# Prove that, $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_i$ is a factor of $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_i^3.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $a_i\in\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}, \forall i\in [1,2n]$ , where $n\in \Bbb N$, such that $\frac {a_1}{a_2}=\frac {a_3}{a_4}=\cdots =\frac {a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n}}$, then prove that,
> $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_i$ is a factor of $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_i^3.$

I tried $n=1$.

$$\frac {a_1^3+a_2^3}{a_1+a_2}=\frac {(a_1+a_2)(a_1^2-a_1a_2+a_2^2)}{a_1+a_2}=a_1^2-a_1a_2+a_2^2.$$

So, this is correct. But I couldn't figure how can I use $\frac {a_1}{a_2}=\frac {a_3}{a_4}=\cdots =\frac {a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n}}$ here. I only proved the problem for $n=1$.

Comment: Just with your approach, it's better to try other cases($n=1, n=2, n=3$ at least) to make sure your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could label ${a_{2i-1}\over a_{2i}} = x$ for all $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$. So we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_i=(1+x)(a_2+a_4+...+a_{2n}) $$

On the other hand we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_i^3=(1+x^3)(a_2^3+a_4^3+...+a_{2n}^3) $$

If the statement is true for all $n$ then it would be true also for $n=3$ and integer vaues of $a_i$. In other words $$E_3:={(x^2-x+1)(a_2^3+a_4^3+a_6^3)\over a_2+a_4+a_6}$$ would be an integer. But his is not the case if $a_2=5$ and $a_4=a_6=1$, since $$E_3= {127\over 7}(x^2-x+1)$$
and say $x=2$.

---

However, the statement does hold for $n=2$ which can be easly verified since $$E_2 ={(x^2-x+1)(a_2^3+a_4^3)\over a_2+a_4} =(x^2-x+1)(a_2^2-a_2a_4+a_4^2) $$

Comment: Are you claiming the question is wrong?

Comment: Have you read what I wrote? You can judge your self.

Comment: Just I couldn't understand the answer.

Comment: @nonuser you say "In other words $E_3$ would be an integer". But I can't see this. How could you conclude this?

Comment: @miracle173 If $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_i$ is a factor of $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_i^3$, then $E_n$ is an integer for integer values of $a_i$. No?

Comment: @nonuser First I was thinking of factors like $\sum \frac 1 {a_i}$, but now I see that makes no sense. The factors should be multivariate polynomials with rational coefficients. But what if the coefficients are not integers?